# Using session->set_flashdata causes 502 Bad gateway error

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, internal-server-error

I am getting 502 bad gateway error when ever I use

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Profile updated.');
```

I am using CodeIgniter on nginx. The code runs fine on localloast(WAMP). If I comment out the lines, application runs fine.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: make sure your session library is loaded

Comment: session library is listed in autoload config file, so it is loaded automatically.

Comment: What's on the server error log? Does this help? http://developernote.com/2012/09/how-i-fixed-nginx-502-bad-gateway-error/

Answer (score 2):

in application/config/config.php set "use_database" to TRUE

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what was wrong. First of all, a colleague with more server knowledge explained me that my setup probably was such that nginx received all the requests, and then directly served static files. for non-static request, it passed on the work to apache, and serves as an intermediary. So probably something went wrong when apache tried to send data to nginx (or when nginx tried to send information to apache).

As I never worked with nginx before, I also did not think of checking the nginx log files. And there was an error that I could use:

[error] 27453#0: *9223 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, client:

I ended up applying the first bit of this other stack overflow solution:

Add this to your nginx.conf file normally located at
Code:
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

proxy_buffer_size   128k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;

By the way, it should be added to the http section of the file. That was something what was missing from the solution.

Reference:
https://forum.codeigniter.com/archive/index.php?thread-59675.html

Answer (score 0):

from @sasho 's answer

$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;

By changing into database you can move session data to database's table to avoid permission related problems. Try and reply here.

```
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html
```

You can see the database driver section from the official documentation to avoid these kind of errors.